# Unexpected behavior in uppercase regexp using Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to have an inbetween step for deleting words backwards, which should stop at a capital letter (in the case of camelCase).

For this I thought to use the following to obtain the position of the first capital letter backwards:

`(search-backward-regexp "[:upper:]")`

If you'd run this when point is after that last parenthesis, it will go here:

`(search-backward-regexp "[:upper | :]")`, that is, after the `r`.

How so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(search-backward-regexp "[[:upper:]]")

`[:upper:]` is not the "upper" call yet, 
 but simply a character class which matches a single character which has to be one of ":" or "u" or "p" or "e" or "r".
Only second "`[]`" makes it search the class.

Comment: Actually `[:upper:]` is simply a character class which matches a single character which has to be one of `:` or `u` or `p` or `e` or `r` (the redundant repeats are ignored). Like you say, the double square brackets are what makes `[[:upper:]]` and its POSIX friends special.

Answer (score 1):

Andreas answer is correct.  However, based on what you are trying to achieve, I would suggest you to take a look to `subword-mode` (it comes bundled with emacs, at least for modern emacsen)

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that it has to do with the variable `case-fold-search`.

When set to `t`, it will ignore case in searches.